# Writing IIS Redirect Rule

Tags: redirect, iis

Sorry, really struggling after Googling so hopefully somebody can help...

If I have a URL in the format {domain}/webinars/Product1, I would like to redirect to {domain}/webinars/Product2. Here is what I have (nb: the second rule to for the PHP controller):

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="v2-r1">
            <match url="^/webinars/Product1" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="/webinars/Product2" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="Hide-Controller" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

If anybody can point me towards what I need to change I'd be very grateful - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I have tested, request **localhost/webinars/Product1** will redirect to **localhost/webinars/Product2**.

```
            <rules>
                <rule name="redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="webinars/Product1" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="webinars/Product2" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
```